# i learnt shallow as well as deep cloning in java.But what is the use of clone() rather directly creating using new

Tags: memory, clone

if we can create instance using new keyword then what is use of clone method .Does it preserve memory?if yes How

Comment: A clone is a copy of an existing instance. A new instance is just that, new, not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Clone does not save any memory.  It creates a new object that has the same data values as the original.  Specifically new Strings, ints etc are created in heap.  Clone is equivalent of using new and a constructor with every single value in the original object.

As you allude a shallow clone, the one inherited from Object, does not create new instances of objects in the new cloned item.  It gets references to the original objects.  So from that perspective you could say you save memory.  But that's seldom what you actually want.  Which is why you have to override clone and instantiate (or clone) the owned objects.

You should use some care with deep cloning because if the higher level object includes a persisted object, e.g. DAO, you can cause quite a mess.  If dealing with DAO you really need to understand your framework.  And it matters a lot what your application wants to do.  Maybe you can just instantiate a detached object, maybe you have to read the database again (and maybe you'll deadlock yourself)!  It all depends on what you need.  I think this is why the lang only supplies a default shallow clone.  Deep cloning you really need to understand what the business goal is.